# Ошибка при работе с json.net

Tags: c#

Вот мой код:

```
JObject test = JObject.Parse(auth_id);
string access_token = (string)test["access_token"][1].ToString();
textBox2.Text = access_token;
```

В `auth_id`:

```
{"access_token":"0533","expires_in":0,"user_id":1}
```

Что не так? Ошибку в третей строчке пишет

**UPD**

Попытался исправить так. Ошибка ушла, но теперь все данные пустые. Что делать?

```
string error = "";
string user_id = "";
string access_token = "";
access_token = ((string)test["access_token"]) == null ? access_token : "";
user_id = ((string)test["user_id"]) == null ? user_id : "";
error = ((string)test["error"]) == null ? error : "";
```

Comment: А какая ошибка? Мы ж не телепаты.

ЗЫ: `string ... = (string)....ToString()` — это вы для верности?

Comment: А зачем там \[1\]? Там же не массив все-таки.

Comment: @Vlmake: Проверять, есть ли такой ключ?

Comment: @Vlmake, если память не изменяет, то:

    if (access_token == null) {
        //обработка ошибки
    }

потому что string либо string, либо null. Хотя наверняка JSON.Net должен сам рапортовать об успехе.

Comment: @Vlmake читайте документацию, там не может не быть примера необходимой проверки на первых же страницах.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: @Vlmake: Ну проявите же немного самостоятельности. Что значит «все данные пустые»? Вы проверяли, или просто в UI ничего не выводится? Пройдите под отладчиком по одной строке. Бросается ли исключение? Какая строка с JSON? Что показывает отладчик, если вы смотрите на `test`? На `test["access_token"]`? На `(string)test["access_token"]`? Выясните, в каком месте начинает что-то идти не так.

Comment: Я решил проблему.

Comment: @Vlmake: тогда расскажите о своём решении, может, понадобится кому-нибудь потом.